# How to run several functions which display information in a GUI one after another?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm pretty new to Python and have started building a GUI that displays news information. I've created five functions which, when called, display the relevant information in the window. Below is a snippet of the functions themselves:

```
# first function which creates new labels and fills them with the relevant site pic,
# first article title, and description.
def fn1():
    label_maker(infoFrame, 0, 0, 630, 389, image=newImage1,
                background='red')
    label_maker(infoFrame, 630, 0, 655, 389, text=entry1.title,
                background='blue', font=("", 20), wraplength=600)
    label_maker(infoFrame, 0, 389, 1286, 389, text=entry1.description,
                wraplength=1250, font=("", 16),
                background='green')


# second function to create labels and fill them with relevant info
def fn2():
    label_maker(infoFrame, 0, 0, 630, 389, image=newImage2,
                background='red')
    label_maker(infoFrame, 630, 0, 655, 389, text=entry2.title,
                background='blue', font=("", 20), wraplength=600)
    label_maker(infoFrame, 0, 389, 1286, 389, text=entry2.description,
                wraplength=1250, font=("", 16),
                background='green')


# third
def fn3():
    label_maker(infoFrame, 0, 0, 630, 389, image=newImage3,
                background='red')
    label_maker(infoFrame, 630, 0, 655, 389, text=entry3.title,
                background='blue', font=("", 20), wraplength=600)
    label_maker(infoFrame, 0, 389, 1286, 389, text=entry3.description,
                wraplength=1250, font=("", 16),
                background='green')


# fourth
def fn4():
    label_maker(infoFrame, 0, 0, 630, 389, image=newImage4,
                background='red')
    label_maker(infoFrame, 630, 0, 655, 389, text=entry4.title,
                background='blue', font=("", 20), wraplength=600)
    label_maker(infoFrame, 0, 389, 1286, 389, text=entry4.description,
                wraplength=1250, font=("", 16),
                background='green')


# fifth
def fn5():
    label_maker(infoFrame, 0, 0, 630, 389, image=newImage5,
                background='red')
    label_maker(infoFrame, 630, 0, 655, 389, text=entry5.title,
                background='blue', font=("", 20), wraplength=600)
    label_maker(infoFrame, 0, 389, 1286, 389, text=entry5.description,
                wraplength=1250, font=("", 16),
                background='green')
```

Also, here is the label_maker function for clarification:

```
# define a new label maker function to construct labels within frames that 
will
#  be placed within infoFrame
def label_maker(master, x, y, w, h, *args, **kwargs):
    frame = Frame(master, width=w, height=h)
    frame.pack_propagate(0)
    frame.place(x=x, y=y)
    label = Label(frame, *args, **kwargs).pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    return label
```

I want to run each of these functions in a rotation of sorts where one function runs for ~15 sec, then the next one runs, then the next and so on until the window is closed. I've tried using the `after()` method but it in the way I used it, the functions ran without displaying anything until the last function was called. How can I loop these one after another and actually have them display the relevant information?

Comment: You could use `time.time()` to get a timestamp, use multiple timestamps to track the time and then call each function at a specific interval

Comment: Build a function that uses `after()` to run each function based off a tracking variable. It Should be rather easy.

Comment: By "runs for ~15 sec", do you really mean that the information displays for about 15 seconds before the information is replaced with new information? The runtime for any one of those functions is measured in milliseconds, so it's impossible for them to "run" for 15 seconds.

Comment: Do you have 5 distinct functions? Why not have one function that takes parameters? It seems really inefficient to have 5 virtually identical functions.

Comment: @BryanOakley: How do you _know_ for sure the functions can't execute that long (since the `label_maker()` function hasn't been defined)?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but because they each only have three statements, and it seems like the statements are simply creating image and text items, and I know that it only takes a few milliseconds to create images and labels, it's a reasonable assumption that the code only runs for a few milliseconds.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands now there is a lot of guess work to do. What is `label_maker` is this part of a gui builder program? Because this does not appear to be normal tkinter code.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I’ve edited the original post to show the label_maker function. Again, I’m quite new to Python so I don’t understand what you mean by “normal tkinter code,” is there something done that is abnormal?

Comment: @ZachGoodman what are your entry values coming from? They are not entry widgets so can you tell me what entr1 through entry5 are? I am just trying to write something that can function but you have a lot going on here. Are each one of your entry items a class of its own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what your `entry1` and other entry values are from. So I just build some dictionaries to use for now.

I think one of the problems you are facing is stacking widgets on top of the last set when you could easily build them once and then update them.

I have reworked your code to be something function on my end and I have made some changes to your label_maker. Please note that your `place()` statement is cause a big visual problem here.

`place()` will not affect the size of your frames so when you only use `place()` for your widgets in the frame then the frame will always be a zero size. Its just not going to work. You need to control the size of your frames some how.

With that said I have simplified the issue by just updating the labels.

Let me know if you have any questions.

I used 3 different colors of squares on my end so I can at least get your code working. Just switch out the different image paths.

The below code will change the labels ever 15 seconds before closing at the end.

```
import tkinter as tk


def manage_time():
    global tracker
    if tracker == 1:
        lbl1.config(image=newImage2)
        lbl2.config(text=entry2['title'])
        lbl3.config(text=entry2['description'])
        tracker = 2
        root.after(15000, manage_time)
    elif tracker == 2:
        lbl1.config(image=newImage3)
        lbl2.config(text=entry3['title'])
        lbl3.config(text=entry3['description'])
        tracker = 3
        root.after(15000, manage_time)
    else:
        root.destroy()

def label_maker(master, x, y, w, h, *args, **kwargs):
    label = tk.Label(master, *args, **kwargs)
    label.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    return label

root = tk.Tk()
tracker = 1
infoFrame = tk.Frame(root, width=500, height=500)
infoFrame.pack()
""" All the code for your images and entry fields"""
entry1 = {"title":"entry1", "description":"description for entry 1"}
entry2 = {"title":"entry2", "description":"description for entry 2"}
entry3 = {"title":"entry3", "description":"description for entry 3"}

newImage1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="./RGB/blue.gif")
newImage2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="./RGB/red.gif")
newImage3 = tk.PhotoImage(file="./RGB/green.gif")

lbl1 = label_maker(infoFrame, 0, 0, 630, 389, image=newImage1, background='red')
lbl2 = label_maker(infoFrame, 630, 0, 655, 389, text=entry1['title'], background='blue',)
lbl3 = label_maker(infoFrame, 0, 389, 1286, 389, text=entry1['description'], background='green')

root.after(15000, manage_time)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried a recursive function, also called manage_time, but with five tracker options that change the labels' information. However when I ran it, I got a maximum recursion depth exceeded error. I also tried just running your example and had the same issue. Should I just change the recursion limit or is there a different way of iterating that could get around this?

Comment: I would have to see what it is your are doing exactly. With my example there should be no way for you to reach a recursion limit.

Comment: Ok so I removed the parentheses when I called manage_time recursively and it runs now, but it doesn't update after 15 seconds to the next set of labels.

Comment: @ZachGoodman is your tracker set and accessible to the function?

Comment: I believe so, I have it initialized as "tracker = 1" right after creating the root window as "root = tk.Tk()" and I have "global tracker" as the first line under manage_time

Comment: Here's the link: https://github.com/hasadi-ha/RSS_Project/blob/master/NewerBuild.py

Comment: You have `==` instead of `=` for each variable assignment. Double quotes are used to check if something is equal to something else. Single quotes are used to assign values. So in your `if/else` statements change `tracker == 2` to `tracker = 1` and do the same all the way to `6`. What you have now will always be tracker 1 because `==` is not changing the value of tracker.

Comment: You would think despite admittedly limited comp sci education I would know that by now haha. Thank you, everything works now.

Comment: @ZachGoodman glad to help. Sometimes the obvious can allude us and it just takes a fresh pair of eyes to see it.